# Count in specific way in awk

Tags: awk, text-processing

I have a problem. This is a small fragment of my input file

```
SOL168 MGD750
SOL259 MGD11
SOL363 MGD38
SOL168 MGD142
SOL363 MGD784
SOL660 MGD752
SOL440 MGD38
SOL440 MGD38
```

I need to count specific repetition. You can count, If in the first column in two different lines you have the same SOL and in the second column you have in one line MGD1-225, you must have in another line MGD 676-900
For example

```
SOL115 MGD201
SOL115 MGD782
```

and this count as one
another example

```
SOL749 MGD751
SOL749 MGD111
```

In my input file, I will expect output

```
2
```

because SOL363 have bonds with MGD38(from the first layer) and also MGD784 (from the second layer)   -   first vertical water bridge

SOL168 have bonds with MGD750 (second layer) and MGD142(first layer)

Now it works, my whole script

```
#!/bin/bash
for index in {1..100} # I do this script on 100 files, that is s why I use for loop
do
awk '
    BEGIN { FS = "MGD" }
    $2 >= 1 && $2 <= 225 { layer1[$1]++ }
    $2 >= 676 && $2 <= 900 { layer2[$1]++ }
    END {
        for (sql in layer1) {
        if (layer1[sql] == 1 && layer2[sql] == 1)
            ++total
    }
    print total
    }
' eq5_15_333_lipid_sol_fragment_$index.ndx >> vertical_water_bridges.txt 
done
```

Comment: Have you tried any awk command for that?

Comment: Remove all the domain-specific language and describe your problem in terms of the strings in your input and the strings in your output and how to transform one to the other.

Comment: @EdMorton I edited now is ok?

Comment: Its a bit better but you still explain things in terms of whatever domain you're working in, e.g. `because SOL363 have bonds with MGD38(from the first layer) and also MGD784 (from the second layer) - first vertical water bridge

SOL168 have bonds with MGD750 (second layer) and MGD142(first layer)`. That doesn't help explain your requirements in a way most of us would understand. You also show a block of input that doesn't contain MGD1-225 or SOL115 and then discuss/show the output you want from them. Simply post concise, sample input and the output you expect **from that input**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `MGD` as your field separator, `$2` becomes the numerical layer indicator and awk can express your problem statement pretty directly:

```
BEGIN { FS = "MGD" }
$2 >= 1 && $2 <= 225 { layer1[$1]++ }
$2 >= 676 && $2 <= 900 { layer2[$1]++ }
END {
    total = 0
    for (sql in layer1) {
        if (sql in layer2)
            ++total
    }
    print total
}


$ awk -f a.awk file
2
```